# get HTML element by attribute value in php

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to extract some data from a webpage with php. The part that I'm interested in is structured similarly to this:

```
<a href="somepath" target="fruit">apple</a>
<a href="somepath" target="animal">cat</a>
<a href="somepath" target="fruit">orange</a>
<a href="somepath" target="animal">dog</a>
<a href="somepath" target="fruit">mango</a>
<a href="somepath" target="animal">monkey</a>
```

First, I want to extract all fruits, and then all animals, so that I have them nicely grouped.

I figured out how to loop through all attribute values. Here's the code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('example.html');

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

for ($i; $i < $a->length; $i++) {
$attr = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('target');

echo $attr . "\n";
}
```

So I get:

```
fruit animal fruit animal fruit animal
```

I also found out how to get the elements' text content:

```
$a->item($i)->textContent
```

So, if included in loop and echoed, I get:

```
apple cat orange dog mango monkey
```

I feel like I'm very close, but I can't get what I want. I need something like this:

if ( target = "fruit") then give me "apple, orange, mango".

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just `continue` on `target` attributes which aren't `fruit`, and then add the `textContent` of the elements to an array.

```
$nodes = array();

for ($i; $i < $a->length; $i++) {
    $attr = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('target');

    if ($attr != 'fruit') {
        continue;
    }

    $nodes[] = $a->item($i)->textContent;
}
```

`$nodes` now contains all the nodes of the elements which have their `target` attribute set to `fruit`.

Answer (score 13):

use `DOMXPath` and queries:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->Load('yourFile.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$fruits = $xpath->query("//a[@target='fruit']");
foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
    // ...
}

$animals = $xpath->query("//a[@target='animal']");
foreach($animals as $animal) {
    // ...
}
```

See [this](http://codepad.org/LiBYq5xR) demo.

Answer (score 3):

Make two array

```
$fruits=array();
$animals=array();
```

t
and in loop when you get .

```
if(target=='fruit') {
   array_push($fruits,$valueofelement);

} else if ($target=='animal') {
   array_push($animals,$valueofelement);
}
```